# Python ImportError: No module named sty

Tags: python, serial-port

I am using python2 in raspbian.
I am trying running esptool.py at raspberry.

`ImportError: No module named sty`

Comment: I confirmed `sty` can be used in python3.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From https://pypi.org/project/sty/

```
Requirements
------------

Sty requires Python ``>= 3.5``
```

So, I am using python3 to run my python file.